# update manager and terminal is not working

Tags: 12.04, updates, release-management

I tried due to previous questions to update in all ways for the new releases 12.04. I tried with update manager and terminal but it's telling me there is no update.

Find bellow the result of terminal command

```
administrator@BANG007:~$ uname -a
Linux BANG007 3.0.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 19 19:05:57 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
administrator@BANG007:~$ uname -r
3.0.0-19-generic
administrator@BANG007:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
administrator@BANG007:~$
administrator@BANG007:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.0.0-19-generic (buildd@vernadsky) (gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) ) #33-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 19 19:05:57 UTC 2012
administrator@BANG007:~$  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:    11.10
Codename:   oneiric
```

and it doesnt find the update????

i am lost now ! any help?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04 see Troubleshooting

Comment: Yes but the same thing ! No result....!!!!!

Comment: You have Internet access? Can you provide the contents of the files in `/etc/update-manager` ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday. Try changing your download server in Software Sources to a different one.

To do this, open the Ubuntu Software Center, click Edit > Software Sources, and select a different (better) server in the *Download from* drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `update-manager -d`?

Comment: i did try update-manager -d but no chance...! Any other idea?